# Best way to shorten time to load front-end JS app / make first JSON API call

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a SPA using Backbone + RequireJS. The document.ready event fires early enough (I believe), but it takes about 500ms for my application to boot up, that is, to make it's first GET request to my server's API. You can see this in these two images from both Firefox and Chrome (Chrome consistently takes a little longer for this operation from what I can tell):

*Chrome browser:*

[image]

*Mozilla browser:*

[image]

Does it normally take about 300-500 ms for the JavaScript to start up in your app, once the .js (in this case .js.gz) file is loaded into the runtime? My application is medium heavy so 500ms seems extreme.

In other words, the JS file is request and loaded at time X and only at time X+400ms does front-end finally get around to making a request, when it should happen as soon as possible (there is nothing else the front-end is waiting on except running the code).

Is there any good explanation for this?

Comment: No, it should not happen. Perhaps you're messing a lot with the DOM in your app init and that's what holding the JS execution?

Answer (score 1):

The 400ms may be the time that browser used to parse and execute your script.

It may be helpful to have a look at the **Timeline** tab in Chrome Dev Tool, which will be much more informative for inspecting what's happening under the hood.

Comment: yes, this seems likely, but 400ms seems excessive. But I am not that familiar with front-end JavaScript, and I don't have a good benchmark in my head about how long it should take,  even though the app I created is pretty sophisticated and modularized.

Comment: @AlexMills how about update the question with a screenshot of Timeline from the beginning to the the first ajax call?

Comment: sure thanks I will put that up tomorrow. i also have console log statements demonstrating that chrome is way slower parsing and executing a big .js file than mozilla